# java Runtime.getRuntime().exec using cat and piping

Tags: java, shell, pipe, cat, runtime.exec

I'm trying to run the following command through java to show the current wifi signal strenght :

```
cat /proc/net/wireless | awk 'END { print $4 }' | sed 's/\.$//'
```

In the terminal this command works fine.

The function I use to run the commands is like :

```
public static String[] executeNativeCommand(String[] commands, String friendlyErrorMessage, String... arguments) throws RuntimeException {
        if (commands == null || commands.length == 0)
            return new String[]{};

        Process listSSIDProcess = null;
        try {
            String[] replacedCommands = new String[commands.length];
            for (int t = 0; t < commands.length; t++) {
                replacedCommands[t] = MessageFormat.format(commands[t], (Object[])arguments);
            }
            listSSIDProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(replacedCommands);
            ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            IOUtils.copy(listSSIDProcess.getInputStream(), output);
            return new String(output.toString()).split("\r?\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (friendlyErrorMessage == null) {
                logger.error("Error masked due to the friendly error message not being set", e);
                return new String[]{};
            }

            throw new RuntimeException(friendlyErrorMessage, e);
        } finally {
            if (listSSIDProcess != null) {
                listSSIDProcess.destroy();
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to call it with :

```
public String getCurrentWiFiStrength(){
        String[] output = IOUtilities.executeNativeCommand(new String[]{"cat /proc/net/wireless | awk 'END { print $4 }' | sed 's/.$//'"}, null);
        if (output.length > 0) {
            logger.info("Wireless strength :" + output);
            return output[0];
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This didn't work so after some stackoverflow research I added /bin/sh and -c like this :

```
public String getCurrentWiFiStrength(){
        String[] output = IOUtilities.executeNativeCommand(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "cat /proc/net/wireless | awk 'END { print $4 }' | sed 's/.$//'"}, null);
        if (output.length > 0) {
            logger.info("Wireless strength :" + output);
            return output[0];
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This didn't work either. So I tried to run through terminal `/bin/sh -c cat /proc/net/wireless | awk 'END { print $4 }' | sed 's/\.$//'`

Which just keeps hanging and doesn't return anything... So I'm not sure what is going on and how to fix this... Any suggestions? I use tinkerOS (a debian based distro)

thanks in advance!

**EDIT :**

So I found out why it didn't work in shell, it was my escaping... The correct syntax is :

/bin/bash -c "cat /proc/net/wireless | awk 'END {print \$4;}' | sed 's/.$//'"

So I tried :

```
public String getCurrentWiFiStrength(){
        String[] output = IOUtilities.executeNativeCommand(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "\"cat /proc/net/wireless | awk 'END {print \\$4;}' | sed 's/.$//'\""}, null);
        if (output.length > 0) {
            return output[0];
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Without too much luck... Any suggestions?

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Comment: *"Any suggestions?"* Don't post an update to the question **as if it was an answer!** Instead [edit] the question to give an update.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Allright thanks for the tip and I did as suggested :)! But the function I use with the exec in it works for all my other commands, just not this one... So it has to do with the way the command is processed... But in shell it works

Comment: Pipes are not understood except by the shell, and you are not executing a shell.

Comment: @EJP well i'm using /bin/sh and that executes the shell... So that should make it work right?